# What is the analytic solution for $y' = -\frac{a}{y} + \frac{b}{y^2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, dynamical-systems

For $y: \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}_+$, if $y'(x) = -\frac{a}{y} + \frac{b}{y^2}$, then $y(x) = ?$

Can anyone give an exact solution of this type?

**Update**: Yes, $a,b$ are some positive constants. By separating the variables and integrating over $x,y$ we have 
\begin{align}
\frac{y^2}{-ay + b} dy &= dx \\
-\frac{2 b^2 \log(b-ay) + a^2 y^2 + 2 a b y}{2 a^3} &= x
\end{align}

For this can we get the explicit formula for $y(x)$?

Comment: Are we to assume $a,b>0$ ? ... This is simple separation of variables. Show us your attempt & we can help.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit I have updated my solution for $x(y)$, while I need some expression of $y(x)$ indeed...

Comment: What you have done is fine & this equation cannot be easily inverted to $y=?$, indeed this equation is will be accepted the required solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Since $-\frac ay+\frac b{y^2}$ is a function of $y$, your differentiable equation is [separable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#Ordinary_differential_equations_(ODE)).

Comment: Thanks! I already get an explicit expression for $x(y)$. However, are we able to get an explicit expression for $y(x)$?

Comment: That seems very unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $y'=-\frac ay+\frac b{y^2}$.  Then,

$$dx=\frac{y^2}{b-ay}\,dy$$

Now integrate and obtain an implicit equation for $y$.

Comment: That's right, but can we have an explicit $y(x)$?